# Lombok: generated constructor missing?

Tags: lombok

For this code:

```
@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Person {

    private @GeneratedValue @Id Long id;
    private final String firstname;
    private String middlename;
    private final String lastname;
}
```

Lombok (v. 1.16.14) should generate two constructors.  First, due to the @Data:

```
public Person(String firstname, String lastname) { ... }
```

Due to the @AllArgsConstructor, there should also be:

```
public Person(Long id, String firstname, String middlename, String lastname);
```

However, the first (two parameter) constructor "disappears" when adding the `@AllArgsConstructor` annotation.  The javadoc for `@Data` states:

```
Equivalent to @Getter @Setter @RequiredArgsConstructor @ToString @EqualsAndHashCode.
```

So am I wrong thinking the two argument ctor should be there?  This has a very simple workaround because if the `@RequiredArgsConstructor` annotation is explicitly added:

```
@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Person {

    private @GeneratedValue @Id Long id;
    private final String firstname;
    private String middlename;
    private final String lastname;
}
```

both ctors are available.  However, this behavior makes little to no sense to me, so I was hoping someone might explain if this is a bug or a feature!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`@Data` only generates constructors if there are none.

[The documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data.html) says: "@Data is like having implicit @Getter, @Setter, @ToString, @EqualsAndHashCode and @RequiredArgsConstructor annotations on the class (except that no constructor will be generated if any explicitly written constructor exists)." Your `@AllArgsConstructor` counts as an explicitly written contructor.

This is a feature.

Disclosure: I am a Lombok developer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!